# Microsoft Access How to Count the Number of Times a Value and all Permutations of that Value is listed in a Field?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a Table and in that table a field named Results with values of 3 digit numbers. I have used the count function to report the number of times a value is repeated in said field with this query.

```
SELECT [My Table].Results, Count([My Table].Results) AS [Total Results]
FROM [My Table]
GROUP BY [My Table].Results;
```

How do I use the count function to also return all combinations of the 3 digit number also repeated in field?

Example

```
Results    Count

123        1
132        1
213        1
789        1
798        1
879        1
897        1
```

After Query I would like the count to show for all values in the field.

```
Results  Count

123      3
132      3
213      3
789      4
798      4
879      4
897      4
```

etc.

Comment: Is there another unique column (like id) in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table on itself, and check if the letters exist in the joined record

```
SELECT [parent].Results, Count([parent].Results) AS [Total Results]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Results FROM [My Table]) parent, [My Table] child
WHERE 
          child.Results = Left(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Right(parent.Results, 1) OR
          child.Results = Left(parent.Results, 1) & Right(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) OR
          child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Left(parent.Results, 1) &  Right(parent.Results, 1) OR
          child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Right(parent.Results, 1) & Left(parent.Results, 1) OR
          child.Results = Right(parent.Results, 1)  & Left(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) OR
          child.Results = Right(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Left(parent.Results, 1)
GROUP BY parent.Results
```

This will replicate each parent row for the number of child rows that contain each symbol of the parent row, and then count the number of rows.

Alternatively, you could use a subquery, but performance of this solution will likely be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I run the above query I get "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Results' as part of an aggregate function."  Sorry I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: @NateBorn See the edit, that one was on me, the last line was not included

Comment: Thanks but when I ran the query the results seem to be counting every single digit in the strings and not the combinations.      These are my first 10 totals. 
000=138312
001=130242
002=143832
003=140530
004=155844
005=108918
006=138207
007=183330
008=164430
009=127365

Comment: Ah, if you have duplicate digits you need to manually iterate the combinations. Since it's only 3 symbols so 3! combinations that's very doable. If you want more characters, the amount of combinations will rapidly increase, so then you'd probably want to use a user-defined function.

Comment: Thanks again I'm getting closer to my goal. My Table consists of a more than 20,000 rows with values ranging from 000 through 999 in one field. Lets say I had a value of 649 in my table I would like the count to only count values of 649, 694, 469, 496, 946 all the combinations of that 3 digit number.  So say that in my field I had only the above six values in my table the total would end up 6 for each occurrence. But I need this done for every 3 digit number 000-999.

Comment: Eh, the current query should just do that. If it doesn't work, please provide further information

Comment: Okay I shorted my table to 79 rows for testing purposes the current 3 digit numbers in table now range from 987-999. When I ran the query the results for 999 where 81 that would be impossible due to there are only 79 records to match with since I'm using a test table now I can count the actual number of times 999 appear and its only 9 times. I used this number for an example because it has the same number for each digit. My guess is some how the 999 values in the table where multiplied by 9. "9*9=81" Also 987 only appears 8 times but query brings back a result of 64. "8*8=64"

Comment: @NateBorn Try the current edit. I hadn't accounted for exactly the same row existing multiple times since that didn't occur in your sample data.

Comment: Thanks I've been trying to figure out how to do this all weekend. Did a whole lot of searching around but couldn't find anyone else with a similar question.

Comment: If this fully answered your question, consider making this answer as accepted. That way, other users can see it has been answered, and you and I get a rep bonus too

Comment: Sorry about that my  first time asking a question.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain the function so I could use this for 4 digit numbers.

Comment: Well, it's just all the combinations iterated. `Left(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Right(parent.Results, 1)` is the first, second and third number in sequence. `Left(parent.Results, 1) & Right(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1)` is first, third, second, etc., so this doesn't scale well at all. If you add a fourth letter, you will have 4! = 24 conditions

Comment: For scaleable solutions, I can write up a VBA one or T-SQL (SQL server) one. Access SQL is limited, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks again I'm a beginner never used VBA.

Comment: Would this function represent 1234 child.Results = Left(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & Right(parent.Results, 1)

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. Now you've gotta do all the combinations